# The Observer Pattern Explained To Myself

Tags: design-patterns

I'm still struggling with the concept of Observer Pattern, so i try to explain it to myself cause i'm not sure I'm right. So perhaps somebody can confirm it's the good approach.
For my example i think about a car with 4 seats. When the 4 seats are taken and the car is driving, the car is checking if everybody has got their seat belt on.
If not, you hear a sound.

[image: UML Diagram]

So i want to observe if the speed is above 10, if the seatbelt is fasten, and if the seat is taken

Is this a good diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, but implementation has flaws.

- Your event source exposes event launcher, breaking SRP.
- All your observers use single subscription point. SpeedObserver will be notified about Belt changes, which is pretty strange and ineffective. Consider exposing multiple typed event sources from Car.

Comment: i think i understand what you are trying me to tell.. SRP single responsibility. So the class should be for example Seat instead of Car?
And a class Speed and Belt as well?